# How to add header to retrofit response in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application i want get data from server and for this i should add some **header** such as **Accept** and **Content_Type** . 
For connect to server i used **Retrofit** library.
For set headers i use **okHttp** client and i write below codes, but not set **header** to api response!
**My Client codes:**

```
class ApiClient() {

    private val apiServices: ApiServices

    init {
        //Gson
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        //Http log
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level =
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE

        //Http Builder
        val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        clientBuilder.interceptors().add(loggingInterceptor)
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader(
                CONTENT_TYPE,
                APPLICATION_JSON
            ).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader(
                ACCEPT,
                APPLICATION_JSON
            ).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }

        //Http client
        val client = clientBuilder
            .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()

        //Retrofit
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL + BASE_URP_PREFIX)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()

        //Init mapApiServices
        apiServices = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    }

    companion object {
        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null

        fun getInstance(): ApiClient =
            apiClient ?: synchronized(this) {
                apiClient
                    ?: ApiClient().also {
                    apiClient = it
                }
            }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option to add a static header is to define the header and respective value for your API method as an annotation. The header gets automatically added by Retrofit for every request using this method. The annotation can be either key-value-pair as one string or as a list of strings.

The example above shows the key-value-definition for the static header:
[image]

Further, you can pass multiple key-value-strings as a list encapsulated in curly brackets {} to the @Headers annotation.

How you can pass multiple key-value-strings as a list encapsulated in curly brackets:
[image]

A more customizable approach are **dynamic headers**. A dynamic header is passed like a parameter to the method. The provided parameter value gets mapped by Retrofit before executing the request.

Define dynamic headers where you might pass different values for each request:
[image]

Happy Coding!!